# Testing index view filtering in RSpec feature spec (Capybara)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

The `index` view of the "users" resource in a Rails 4.2 app is capable of filtering the displayed users by their `role` (such as in "admin" or "user") and `country` attributes.

The application uses Devise, so we need to create a user record in order to login. Note that the user created for login purposes inevitably appears in our test data.

I'd like your help to improve these tests (which are currently working) or to identify a better way to test a filter feature.

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_single_record do |id|
  match do |page|
    expect(page).to have_selector("tr.user", count: 1)
    expect(page).to have_selector("tr#user_#{id}")
  end
  failure_message do |page|
    "expected to find a single record in the page with id #{id}. " \
    "Found #{page.all("tr#user_#{id}").count} records instead."
  end
end

describe "User CRUD", type: :feature, js: true do
  # Create user for logging-in with Devise
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }
  before(:each) { login_as(user) }

  describe "filtering" do
    it "filters by role" do
      # The logged in user has :admin role
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, role: :user)
      visit index_view_path
      select "user", from: "q_role_eq"
      # It auto-submits
      expect(page).to have_single_record(user.id)
    end

    it "filters by country" do
      # The country of the logged in user is "US"
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, country: "BR")
      visit index_view_path
      select "Brazil", from: "q_country_eq"
      # It auto-submits
      expect(page).to have_single_record(user.id)
    end
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: you don't need `let!` -- just `let` will suffice as it is used in the `before` section

Comment: you probably want an expectation before triggering the filter that confirms there is more than 1 user shown, otherwise you're not really confirming the filter does anything.  May be a more appropriate question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I haven't thought of that as another test ensures all existing records are displayed on this page. However, if a problem occurs in the creation of the test data (within this test), it may pass even if the filter does nothing. So I have added the expectation you suggested. Thank you.